# Getting Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set) in special case

Tags: django, pandas, matplotlib, django-csrf

I have a post method which look like following

```
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import pandas as pd

    class VisualizeSingleStock(APIView):
        """
        Return the behaviour of the particular stock in all time
        """

        def post(self, request):
            """
             ---
            parameters:
                - name: stock_id
                  description: stock id which behaviour you want to see in all time
                  type: string
                  required: true
            """
            fig = Figure()
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(EquityData.objects.filter(stock=str(request.data['stock_id'])).values())
            df = df.set_index(['date'])
            del df['stock']
            del df['id']
            df.plot(subplots=True)
            canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
            plt.close(fig)
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
            canvas.print_png(response)
            return response
```

here i am fetching stocks from database and plot it with date as x-axis and rest columns as y-axis but when i hit api i get  CSRF cookie not set. and django-rest-swagger shows no image in response with 200 OK resultcode.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you call this view?

Comment: @knbk sorry for late reply but I will call this api with following   url(r'^equityfeed/visualize_single_stock/$', views.VisualizeSingleStock.as_view(), name='VisualizeSingleStock'),

Comment: I mean, how do you call it from the browser?